# Missing Helper error in cakephp blog tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Im just starting out with php and cakePhp in general. I encountered the following error while trying to implement the blog tutorial. 
I have followed the steps in the tutorial till here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#creating-post-views

Screenshots of the error msgs are here-

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb262.png "top"

 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjG2z.png "bottom"

Model/Post.php

```
    <?php        
   class Post extends AppModel {}
```

Controller/PostsController.php

```
    <?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array(’Html’, ’Form’);

public function index() {
    $this->set(’posts’, $this->Post->find(’all’));
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    $this->set(’post’, $this->Post->read());
}}
```

Posts/index.ctp

```
     <h1>Blog posts</h1>
     <table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Created</th>
</tr>

<!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
     array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($post); ?>
```

Comment: @Ross added code from files.

Comment: check my answer for the first problem.
For the second, it must be resolved by the change that i post in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace " ’ "   by a simple quote " ' ".

so you must declare helpers as :

```
      public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
```

the same change for find method param :

```
      $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
```

at last

```
      $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
```

Anas

Comment: Thanks @Anas . Can't believe it was so simple. I was earlier using the pdf version of the cookbook and I think thats where the different quotes came from while copying the code.

Comment: @user603125 never copy/paste code while you're learning! It's much better to type it down yourself since:
1. you will think through what you're typing
2. you will have a greater understanding of the code
3. you will get muscle memory for typing
In general copy/pasting code while learning is a VERY BAD PRACTICE.